# Is this another way of saying T is a set of multiples of 3 in N?

Tags: education

Is this another way of saying T is a set of multiples of 3 in N?
[image: question]

Comment: I would interpret (but I'm not a native english speaker) "a set of multiples of $3$ in $\mathbb N$ as a subset of the set $T$ which I would probably call "the natural numbers that are multiples of $3$".

Comment: What is the lower case $t$ for? That part doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

$T=3\Bbb N$ is a commonly used shorthand for your definition. But yes, your definition works. Just get rid of "$:t$ in there, and write "$T=\{\cdots\}$" directly.

Reading your question a bit more, if you just want to say that $T$ is some set containing only multiples of $3$, but not necessarily all of them, then you shouldn't use $\{\cdots\}$, since those are used for when you want to give an exact description of a specific set. Instead, say that all elements of $T$ are multiples of $3$:$$\forall t\in T\exists n\in \Bbb N(t=3n)$$

Comment: But isn't this just another way of writing it and not describing  it, although I don't know how it would be done.

Comment: @johnnobody That's why I called it a shorthand. The actual definition cannot be done much shorter. It is, however, "another way of saying that $T$ is the set of multiples of $3$ in $\Bbb N$", which is what was asked for.